# JQuery calculating amount (with comma)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a JQuery function to calculate the amount including the tax. When I want to set a amount with cents I need to use a dot. It will be like 125.25 euro's. I would like to know how to calculate the amount including tax by using a comma.

here is my code:

```
    if($("#tax").val() == "verlegd") { var tax= 0;  }
    else 
    { 
        var tax= parseInt($("#tax").val()); 
    }

    var taxCalc = parseInt(100+tax);
    var amount= parseFloat($("#amount").val());

    var amountinc = Math.round(((amount* taxCalc) / 100)*100)/100;
    if(!isNaN(amount)) 
    { 
        $("#amountinc").val(amountinc); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        $("#amountinc").val("unvalid number");
    }
}

$("#amount").keyup(function(){ updateTotalExc(); });
$("#tax").change( function(){ updateTotalExc(); });
```

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do is replace all commas in the input with dots, and then do your calculation. That way the user can enter commas or dots, whichever suits her best.

Comment: Remove your commas from the Amount [ie - Eg - 10,00,000.45 to 1000000.45] then perform the calc.

Comment: Do you mean `comma as a decimal separator` or `comma as a thousands separator`?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: comma as a decimal separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, you can use `replace` to change all commas to dots within the `#amount` value.

```
var amount = $("#amount").val().replace(',', '.');
```

Comment: ... and wrap it with `parseFloat()` to get a number

Comment: what do you mean with wrapping it with parseFloat() ?
This function works, but when I save both amounts in my db the first one with comma will be saved as 13 instead of 13.50

Answer (score 3):

You can use regexp to remove all comma before get your tax value:

```
    var tax= parseInt($("#tax").val().replace(/,/g,''));
```

It will change `10,000,000.25` to `10000000.25`

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use JavaScript as well.

```
tax = tax.replace(",",".");
```